# Installing a program through MAC Command Line, by putting binary in my PATH

Tags: macos, command-line, path, terminal

So i'm fooling around with the Terminal.

Can someone explain to me how to install a program by putting it's **Binary in my PATH**.

I am assuming I go $PATH/ --Binary--

If the above is the case,

1) Why does this install the program?

2) Is there a standardized method to find a 'downloads' binary?

I am sure there are better ways of installing programs. I am interested in this specific method though.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The PATH is a shell variable that tells the shell where programs may be found. It is a list of places to look for executable programs and scripts, separated by colons (`:`). For example:

```
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

So, when you run a program by typing:

```
program
```

the shell looks first in `/bin`, then in `/sbin` and so on, until it finds `program`, then it runs that.

So, if you want to install a binary (or program, or script) just put it anywhere on your PATH. Or put it somehwere new, not on your PATH, and change your PATH to tell the shell where you have put it.

In general, you would want to set your PATH in your login profile, which may be ~/.profile or elsewhere so that it is set each time you log in. To do that, add a line like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/some/additional/place
```

If you want to find out which is the actual program that will be run when you type

```
program
```

you can run

```
which program
```

For example, if you want to know which `sed` you are running, type

```
which sed
```

and it will probably tell you somethimg like

```
/usr/bin/sed
```

Regarding your second question, about a `standard downloads area`, I am not sure if you mean a standard place to find binaries, or a standard place to install them. There is no `standard downloads` area to obtain binaries, though for Mac OSX, many people use `homebrew` or `macports`. If you mean a standard place to put them, it is normal to install software that doesn't come from the OS author, into `/usr/local/bin`, so that all local binaries are separate from those issued with the OS itself.

Comment: Does the `/usr/local/bin` directory also apply for downloads of software that have to be built? If so, should we store the entire untarred root directory there or just the resulting binaries from the build? If the download already has a `bin` directory, should we just store the `bin` directory in /usr/local/bin or the entire downloaded untarred directory?

Comment: In general, you wouldn't store the entire software distribution of anything you have downloaded in `/usr/local/bin`. Normally, you would build it somewhere else, and either copy the resulting binaries into `/usr/local/bin` (probably using the `install` tool) or add into your `PATH` the directory containing the binaries.

Comment: Thanks! I just felt weird because I was untarring everything in `/Users/username/Development/Tools`, and I wasn't sure if this was a best practice.

Comment: I am installing something that has a `bin` folder where the executable and other files are there, where should I put something like this?

Comment: @cryanbhu It depends what it is, how it is installed and who it's for. If it's something small you wrote yourself, and it's just for your user and not others on the same system, probably `$HOME/bin`. If it's a well-known package with a `Makefile` and `configure` script, you probably want to configure it to go in `/usr/local/bin` and do a `make install`.